# Send JSON data with jquery ajax request and receive response from Controller in Spring

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I need some help, I want to make a jquery ajax request to obtain some data and then to save them in controller. I obtain the fields correctly but when I push the button nothing happens.

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
add:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (add:190)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org ">

<head>
    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>


</head>

<body>
<nav th:replace="layouts :: foo"></nav>
<div class="container my-5">
    <h3>Adauga masini :</h3>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label for="model" class="col-form-label">Model</label> <input type="text"
                                                                                           class="form-control"
                                                                                           id="model"
                                                                                           placeholder="Model"
                                                                                           required>
                        </legend>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label for="year" class="col-form-label">An fabricatie :</label>
                        </legend>
                        <select name="year" id="year">
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label class="col-form-label">Combustibil :</label><br>
                        </legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="fuel" value="benzina +  gpl"
                               required> benzina+gpl<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="fuel" value="motorina + gpl"
                               required> motorina+gpl<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="fuel" value="motorina"
                               required> motorina<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="fuel" value="benzina"
                               required> benzina

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label for="seats" class="col-form-label">Numar locuri :</label>
                        </legend>
                        <select name="seats" id="seats">
                            <option value="two">2</option>
                            <option value="four">4</option>
                            <option value="six">6</option>
                            <option value="eight">8</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label for="color" class="col-form-label">Culoare :</label> <input type="text"
                                                                                               class="form-control"
                                                                                               id="color"
                                                                                               placeholder="Color"
                                                                                               required>

                        </legend>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label class="col-form-label">Cutie viteze :</label><br>
                        </legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="gear"
                               value="automat" required> automata<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="gear"
                               value="manual" required> manuala<br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <legend>
                            <label for="price" class="col-form-label">Pret :</label></legend>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="price"
                               placeholder="Price"
                               required>

                        <select id="coin">
                            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                            <option value="USD">USD</option>
                            <option value="LEI">LEI</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button onclick ="addCar()" class="btn btn-primary" >Add car</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-8"></div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/cars/list">Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function addCar() {
           let model = document.getElementById('model').value;
           console.log(model);
           let year = document.getElementById('year').value;
           console.log(year);
           let fuel = $("input[name='fuel']:checked").val();
           console.log(fuel);
           let seats = document.getElementById('seats').value;
           console.log(seats);
           let color = document.getElementById('color').value;
           console.log(color);
           let gear = $("input[name='gear']:checked").val();
           console.log(gear);
           let price = document.getElementById('price').value;
           console.log(price);
           let coin = document.getElementById('coin').value;
           console.log(coin);


      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { model: model , year: year , fuel: fuel , seats: seats, color: color , gear: gear, price: price, coin: coin },
            url: "/cars/add",
            success: function(result) {
              window.location.href = '/cars/list';
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              var response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
              var errMessage = response["message"];
              alert(errMessage);
            }
      });
}


</script>

<script>

    var start = 1900;
    var end = new Date().getFullYear();
    var options = "";
    for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
      options += "<option>"+ year +"</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/cars/add")
public @ResponseBody String addCars(Cars car,
                                    @RequestParam("model") String model,
                                    @RequestParam("year") int year,
                                    @RequestParam("fuel") String fuel,
                                    @RequestParam("seats") int seats,
                                    @RequestParam("color") String color,
                                    @RequestParam("gear") String gear,
                                    @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                    @RequestParam("coin") String coin) {
    System.out.println(model);
    System.out.println(year);
    car.setModel(model);
    car.setYear(year);
    car.setFuel(fuel);
    car.setSeats(seats);
    car.setColor(color);
    car.setGearBox(gear);
    car.setPrice(price);
    car.setCoin(coin);

    return "redirect:/cars/list";
}``
```

I want to save those car details in database and to redirect to a page where I have a list with those cars

Comment: afaik you need to tell your spring endpoints the datatype that is consumes and that it produces and i do not think that JSON is the default. so something like `@PostMapping(path = "/myPath", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")` PS. that means that you do not need 1 RequestParam for each key -value pair ... you only need one and usally you want to hydrate that into some object (`@RequestBody Car car`)

Comment: And how can I do that? I don't get how to use just one RequestParam

Comment: Hi, I have already a form for uploads photos, and I need a an Ajax request for these fields